after updating to 23.10, application crashes, wrong update sources(?) and problems installing .deb apps
Good morning, I'll start by saying what I've done so far, then I'll move on to my questions, so I can put you in context. I started using Linux with Ubuntu about two weeks ago. To install Ubuntu I only had a 4GB pendrive available. I then installed ubuntu 20.04 LTS. I did all the updates up to 22.04LTS. I edited the updates file, from LTS to normal, to install ubuntu 23.10 to have the latest version of GNOME.
Now, if I look at "Software and Updates" in the "Other software" section I find myself with all sources of 20.04 Focal Fossa and they have not updated to 23.04. How do I get new updates if the sources are 20.04? Do I have to change them manually?
There are various applications that continually give me errors, such as "Chat GPT" or "Webapp-manager (mint)", two apps that I use very frequently. Are you also experiencing problems with these two applications? Are they based on another version of the Kernel?
Another problem occurs when I try to install a .deb file, "Ubuntu software" opens normally, but sometimes the page remains blank, and other times the page appears, I click on install, and the animated line continues to light up installation but it doesn't install anything at all. Why?
Being new to Linux, these are questions that could be "stupid" in the eyes of those who know this world, for example I could give myself simple answers to these same questions but on Windows.
If you need any other information, ask me, so I can get it to you later. Many thanks to all!

I think this is the problem: a move from 20.04 to 23.10 is called an upgrade, and you don't do it by editing "the updates file". It would be a good idea to reinstall, and if you don't want to get a bigger pendrive, try the mini iso of 24.04.
